# Entity Framework Core Find and Composite Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The `Find()` method takes an array of objects describing the primary key you're attempting to find. The documentation is unclear as to how to handle composite primary keys. I tried searching the GitHub repository, but was unable to find the source code for the `Finder.Find()` method.

For example, I've used the fluent API to define the following composite primary key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
    .HasKey( x => new { x.CommunityID, x.ArticleID } );
```

Do I call `Find()` like this:

```
Find( new object[] {1, 2} );
```

or like this:

```
Find( new object[] { new {CommunityID = 1, ArticleID = 2} } );
```

If it's the first approach, is the order of the parameters the same as the order of properties defined on the fluent API anonymous object?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Find has a signature of: `params object[] keyValues`

No need to pass in an array, just each key separately:

```
.Find(1, 2);
```

> If it's the first approach, is the order of the parameters the same as
>   the order of properties defined on the fluent API anonymous object?

Yes, you'll need to pass in the PKs in the same order as defined within your fluent API map.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: Thanx. So the parameter order to Find matches the sequence in which the fluent API call is made?

Comment: @MarkOlbert Indeed. The description of the parameter is *The values of the primary key for the entity to be found.*, what else it could be. In other words, the fluent API defines the PK columns, `Find` expects the PK column values.